# toLocaleString() is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**Update:**

[image]

**Original:**

Could you tell me why `toLocaleString()` is not working here? It works in all other places. I need it to give `1000 separators`. Any clue or work around?

```
 forEach(budgetList, async (b: Budget) => {
          const budget: Budget = find(this.oldBudgetList, (budget: Budget) => {
            return b.budgetGroup.name == budget.budgetGroup.name;
          });
          if (budget == null) {//new item
            const log = this.logProvider.getLogDetails(`Budget : ${b.budgetGroup.name}`, `Added ${b.amount.toLocaleString()}`, 'project', project.id);
            await this.logProvider.createLog(log, project.id);//add log
          } 
        });
```

*Runtime:*

[image]

Another place and works well!

```
const log = this.logProvider.getLogDetails('Project : Budget', `Budget changed from ${this.oldBudgetValue.toLocaleString()} to ${project.budget.toLocaleString()}`, 'project', project.id);
await this.logProvider.createLog(log, project.id);//add log
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if `b.amount` is *already* a string? If so, `.toLocaleString()` would be found on the Object prototype, and it would do nothing useful.

Comment: `b.amount` is a `number`. But we can convert it to a string using this no `toLocaleString`? All other places like so, @Pointy

Comment: Could you `console.log(typeof b.amount)` and update the question with the result

Comment: @Sampath how do you **know** it's a number? Have you checked? It seems vastly more likely that *your* code has a bug than that your JavaScript runtime system is defective.

Comment: Yes, `console.log(typeof b.amount)` shows as `string`? @Pointy What should I do?

Comment: If it is a string, do like this: `parseInt(b.amount).toLocaleString()` or `parseFloat(b.amount).toLocaleString()`

Comment: I have tried this `parseInt(b.amount).toLocaleString();` Then it shows error `Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'` @LGSon

Comment: Well if it's *supposed* to be a number but it isn't, then there must be a bug somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the direction @LGSon This works `Number(b.amount).toLocaleString()`. Please put it as an answer. Then I can close this post.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support too :) @Pointy

Comment: The better solution would be to fix how `b.amount` is set so that it *is* a number instead of a string.

Comment: Yes, It is a `number`. This is a very strange use case. `export class Budget {
    id: string;
    amount: number;
    contingency: number = 20;
    budgetGroup: BudgetGroup = new BudgetGroup();
    creationTime: string;
}` @JohnnyHK

Comment: Please see the **update** too. I don't have any explanation here. Simply amazing :D It works well without `Number` in other places. @JohnnyHK

Comment: That image just show what the IDE understands how `amount` is defined in the class. You're likely creating that object incorrectly so that its value is a string. I think you'll need to create a [MCVE] if you still want help getting to the bottom of this.

Comment: OK, Thanks for the feedback. Just for the time being, I would like to swallow current workaround :) @JohnnyHK

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If the value is of type `String`, you could do e.g.

```
Number(b.amount).toLocaleString()
```

(which was what was working in OP's case)

---

Other options could be

```
parseInt('number as string').toLocaleString()

parseFloat('number as string').toLocaleString()
```